# How to use Apache Commons Validator for urls without protocol

Tags: java, validation, apache-commons

Using Apache Commons Validator 1.4.0. Till now was using the `GenericValidator.isUrl("http://google.com")` which works fine with URLs which have protocol with them. It returns `false` in case protocol is missing.

How can I use the `UrlValidator` to validate URLs that do not contain any protocol? Should I use plain regex to do so. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apache [commons-httpclient](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1) and its class [URI](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/URI.html). It has many methods which you can use to validate URI with certain properties (e.g. being relative or absolute, having particular schema or not, …).